# What do we mean by saying: Narcissist are not empathetic?

Tags: clinical-psychology

I was amazed by finding out the [dark triad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_triad) 
But I have a doubt. I know some "narcissists" and I would not say that they cannot see other people emotions. I would say that they think they have the right to disrespect them or they cannot realize when they are disrespectful.

For example, I imagine the following beliefs from a narcyssist:
People have to make effort
Who doesn't make effort doesn't deserve pity

Or

Bullism is very bad
Who is a bullist doen't deserve to live

Of course seeing emotions and respecting them is really different.. Narcyssism is ONLY about not perceiving other emotions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The people you know may have narcissictic personality traits, but that doesn't mean that they meet all the criteria. Criteria lists can be very confusing. Most of the time, people who are diagnosed with mental illnesses *don't* meet all the clinical criteria, even if their pathology is quite severe.

I don't think the statements you give are necessarily narcissitic. A statement that describes the style of lack of empathy of a narcissicist might be something like, "I don't care if you want to eat pasta, because I want to eat sushi and what I want is more important." This is how psychology usually describes lack of empathy: a pathological inability to recognize that other people's feelings are equally as valid as one's own.

At any rate, lack of empathy is only one of several features of narcissicistic personality.